# UITableView all components are changed background color when selecting cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm customizing the cell of **tableview**. The cell included 2 buttons(one is red and another is blue). But when I select the cell, 2 buttons were changed background color to the highlighted cell color. I want they keep their color when the cell is highlighted. My solution is to capture the highlighted delegate of `tableview` and change the background of the buttons.

Can any one give me another solution?

Thanks

Comment: Check my answer with what you asked in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override `setHighlighted` and `setSelected` inside your `UITableViewCell` subclass

**Objective C**

```
-(void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    UIColor *someViewColor = self.someView.backgroundColor;
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted animated:animated];
    self.someView.backgroundColor = someViewColor;
}

-(void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    UIColor *someViewColor = self.someView.backgroundColor;
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    self.someView.backgroundColor = someViewColor;
}
```

**Swift**

```
override func setHighlighted(highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool) {

    let someViewColor = someView.backgroundColor        
    super.setHighlighted(highlighted, animated: animated)
    someView.backgroundColor = someViewColor
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {

    let someViewColor = someView.backgroundColor        
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    someView.backgroundColor = someViewColor
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quickly answer. It's great.